# How to identify correlation in product sales and generate new products

Tags: correlation, prediction

My final project at college is a "selling software", where i have the list of products (ice cream) and the sells.
Its all done, but since im new with ML, i dont know which lib to use to achieve my goal: Analyse the top selling products, identify which ingredients are common in them, and with it, generate new products.
The idea is: top 5 selling products:
IceCream1: [Chocolate, Strawberry]
IceCream2: [Chocolate, Condensed Milk]
IceCream3: [Condensed Milk, Strawberry]
IceCream4: [Vanilla, Strawberry]
IceCream5: [Chocolate, Strawberry, Vanilla]
Then, since the top selling products have chocolate, strawberry, and Condensed milk, it would sugest a new ice cream with those 3 ingredients.

Plus if possible: based on the sells number of all products, predict how much this new product would sell.

Ps: front end has made with Angular, backend in Node and DB is MongoDB.

Any help/suggestion will be really appreciated! 
Thanks guys :D